# Jquery - Gridview - alternate row color

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with alternate row colors.

[image]

if you double click on the grid where it is empty--> it changes to green and adds text MI-->if you double click on Green MI --> It should go back to previous state (original state with empty text , same background color)

Right now everything is working except if I click on odd row number instead of going to blue it is turning to white.

Current code I have is

```
                $('#MainContent_GVTest>tbody>tr>td').dblclick(function (e) {

                var selTD = $(e.target).closest("td");

                var selTR = $(e.target).closest("tr");

                 if (($.trim($currentCellText) == "MI") && $(selTD).attr('class') == "firsttime") {
                    selTD.text("");
                    selTD.addClass("NoClass");

                   }
        }); // This is working as expected
```

I want to add more logic depending on the even row /odd row to get the correct back color. something like below. But it is not working. How can I fix it?

```
                       if ($(selTD).is(":even")) {
                        alert('Even****************')
                         selTD.addClass("NoClass");
                        }
                    if ($(selTD).is(":odd")) {
                        alert('Odd****************')
                        selTD.addClass("NoClassOddrow");
                    }



                         .NoClass
                            {
                              background-color: white;
                                 }

                              .NoClassOddrow
                                 {
                                  background-color:blue;
                                      }
```

I updated the code. When I update code to above and I double click on 1st Blue cell I get Alerted saying Odd, Changes the color to Blue

But when I click on row below again it is alerting Odd and changing the color to Blue.

Comment: _if I click on odd row number instead of going to blue it is turning to white._  Your `.NoClassOddrow` has the style `background-color:#fff;` which is a white background.

Comment: Changing my Code. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is odd that you have a class called `NoClass`. If I was you I would create a class for highlighting the odd and even rows.

Something like this:

```
#MainContent_GVTest tr:nth-child(even) td.highlight { background-color:green; }

#MainContent_GVTest tr:nth-child(odd) td.highlight { background-color:red; }
```

Then you could toggle that class in javascript like this:

```
$('#MainContent_GVTest>tbody>tr>td').dblclick(function (e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. You can add your custom logic for `"MI"` and `"firsttime"` in the `dblclick` event as needed.